# Does kingo root trigger knox on s4?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-knox

And also I plugged my phone in but kingo root won't recognize it and it says connection to server failed

Answer (score -1):

no it doesnt trigger knox and try another computer to fix the connection error, happened to me

Comment: Did it fix it for you?

Comment: And also does knox support 4.4.2? Cause I think I heard somewhere that they don't support it